# Does Eclipse have a tool to merge a type hierarchy into a single class?

Tags: java, eclipse

Does eclipse have a tool that can create `Merged` from `A` and `B` ?

```java
public class A {
    int a;

    public int getA(){
        return A;
    }
}
```

```java
public class B extends A {
    int b;

    public int getB(){
        return b;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Merged {
    int a;
    int b;

    public int getA(){
        return A;
    }
    public int getB(){
        return b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think so. It's not so simple task. Your example is simple, but consider this:

```
class A {
    private int a;
    public void foo(){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

class AA extends A {
    private int a; //its not the same 'a'!!
    public void foo(){ //ok, we override, so we can 'overwrite', but...
        super.foo(); //... what with this?
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

As you can see, its hard to automate. And what if some class in this hierarchy extends some lib class, for which you don't have sources?
So, merging is hard, and very very bad, thats why I don't think anyone wrote such tool.

Comment: I just found Refactor->Push Down/Push Up.

Comment: **Refactor -> Push Up / Push Down**

moves fields and methods up and down the type hierarchy. It also updates occurences. But as Adam Jurczyk says it will most likely result in some errors. Especially when the types reference each other or have indentical field/methods (equals(),hashCode(), serialVersionUID)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This is the tool you need, for simple cases. For cases like the one given by me, it simple merges code and warns about overlaps. Heh, you live and learn :D